# Why Ajax headers property doesn't work but beforeSend event works in sending http headers to server?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to decorate the form and try to send the token in an ajax call, at the beginning I used code below:

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: newurl,
     headers: {'__RequestVerificationToken': token},
     data: form.serialize(),
     datatype: "JSON",
     success: function..,
     error: function..
})
```

And it didn't work, server didn't get value I set in the above headers for __RequestVerificationToken, but kept using some old token value.

However, after I switched the "headers" line to the one below, it picked up the token I set.

```
     beforeSend: function (request)
     {
       request.setRequestHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", token);
     },
```

How come headers doesn't work, but only beforeSend works? So far I couldn't find any clue through online search. 
Headers was introduced in jQuery 1.5 and is in the documentation: 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1, and .Net MVC 5.1.

Comment: Your using `form.serialize()` which will include the token. There is no need at all for the `headers` option.

Comment: But it didn't work for me, the server didn't get the token in request headers, also, using headers property of ajax didn't work for me as well

Comment: If you `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is inside your `<form>` tags, then `.serialize()` will serialize it.

Comment: You're correct, it's serialized, but request header didn't get it.

Comment: You do not need to set it in the header :) It will be sent to the controller in the body

Comment: You mean using [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on controller actions? We chose manually checking AntiForgeryToken for ajax calls in our application. We're doing this checking globally in some Authorization filter

Comment: Yes, if your method has the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` it will all be handled correctly by the framework

Comment: I didn't try it out, but would it work for ajax calls as well? If so, that may be a design issue on our side..

Comment: Yes it works for ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

I set a debugger in jQuery's setRequestHeader method, it turned out that it was called multiple times through the ajax call:

1st:

```
Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

2nd:

```
Accept "*/*"
```

3rd:

```
__RequestVerificationToken [the token I set]
```

But it was also called the 4th time, to set __RequestVerificationToken as well:

```
__RequestVerificationToken [some other token]
```

By tracking the call stack, I found in our application framework there is a $.ajaxSetup method

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", environment.antiForgeryToken);
   }
});
```

That was the culprit that overwrote the token I set. By using 'beforeSend' in my ajax call, the 'beforeSend' in ajaxSetup is not called.